# Unity "ContainerControlled" Singletons and multi-threaded method calling

Tags: c#, multithreading, dependency-injection, singleton, unity-container

I'm using Microsoft Unity for Dependency Injection (DI).  My classes are basically static (in functionality but not coding/calling conventions) except that I want DI, so I use Unity and Constructors which auto-resolve other Unity classes.

Since this is a singleton pattern, can multiple threads execute the same code block at the same time?

i.e. Let's say I have an Add method, which returns an int, and takes as input, two ints...

Can multiple-threads invoke this Add method on the same singleton object, at the same time?  Or because it's the same instance, do threads block waiting to invoke?

To put it another way, is there any difference between method calling for a static method, vs. a singleton instance method?

(I know any shared data used from within the singleton instance methods must be made thread safe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. Thread safety is only important when you have some ***shared state*** that you need to protect. A method like you described - simple add operation - that gets all the relevant context in the call stack requires no protection so you can safely use it in multi-threaded environment.

There is of course a difference between an instance method call and a static method call, in both functional and non functional areas. Static methods are considered to be negligibly faster than instance methods, but they cannot be used effectively in polymorphic software designs - (well, at least not in C#)

Comment: So there is no blocking for multiple threads to call the same instance method, from the same object, at the same time, correct?

Comment: Correct. No Blocking, unless you want it to block, in which case you use the lock statement.